# Changing a char array without even calling the array?

Tags: c++, pointers, chararray

I have studied c++ for about 2 weeks on cave of programming (while working full time :( ) and I just got an understanding for pointers. `Point *pThis` to `&thi`s to get the value out of this address and so on. Anyway, I just got to a video that flipped everything I knew.

I had to copy this to paper first because I am not at home I hope it is correct!

```
char text[] = "hello";

int nChars = sizeof(text) - 1;

char *pStart = text;
char *pEnd = text + nChars - 1;

while(pStart < pEnd)
{
    char save = *pStart;
    *pStart = *pEnd;
    *pEnd = save;

    pStart++;
    pEnd--;
}

cout >> text >> endl;
```

I hope I wrote it correct from this video with my phone

https://youtu.be/g9oMn4mEx14

I do understand that we are creating two pointers that points to the start and end of text and then switching them and so on. What I don't understand is how can it change text without us even assigning anything to that char array anywhere? This boggles my mind.

I hope someone can help me get this :)

Comment: `int i = 5; int *pi = &i; *pi = 6; printf("%d\n", i);` <- prints 6. what????? how can `i` be 6 when we didn't even call that int anywhere?

Comment: The code in the loop does a s swap of values and moves the start and end each 1 step closer to each other.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow expects a certain amount of effort on your part. Please take the time to sit down at a computer when possible, and write the code, and run the program. Posting code with pointers that you wrote by hand is not going to be well received.

Comment: The changing is done here `*pStart = *pEnd;` and here `*pEnd = save;`. This is normal, you have a pointer, you dereference it and assign. That changes whatever the pointer is pointing to, in this case elements of the `text` array.

Answer (score 4):

Draw it on paper (still the best method to both understand and write code with pointers).
Here is an ASCII version:

The beginning:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^               ^
  |               |
 pStart         pEnd
```

The loop:

```
save = *pStart;

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o | 0 |       save: h
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^               ^
  |               |
 pStart         pEnd
```

Then:

```
*pStart = *pEnd;

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | e | l | l | o | 0 |       save: h
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^               ^
  |               |
 pStart         pEnd
```

Then:

```
 *pEnd = save;

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | e | l | l | h | 0 |       save: h
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^               ^
  |               |
 pStart         pEnd
```

And then:

```
pStart++;
pEnd--;

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | e | l | l | h | 0 |       save: h
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^       ^
      |       |
    pStart   pEnd
```

and you can repeat the loop yourself.
(It's much faster and easier on paper than with a computer and a keyboard.)

Answer (score 0):

> how can it change text without us even assigning anything to that char array anywhere? This boggles my mind.

Because the char array acts like a pointer - it's just an address to where the characters are stored. You want to be changing the characters themselves. The location in memory where the array is remains constant here.

Comment: Thank you Unslander! Now I get it!

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this to pseudocode, we are essentially swapping the characters at the start and end pointers using a temp variable `save`.

In the code snippet you just posted, this occurs in 3 steps:

- store `start` to `save`
- store `end` to `start`
- store `save` to `end`